# JointJS: Require target element when creating link

Tags: jointjs

I am trying to avoid links ending up in space and I want to only allow links connecting one element with another. My current code is:

```
new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
  id: id,
  size: {
    width: width,
    height: height
  },
  attrs: {
    text: {
      text: label,
      'font-size': letterSize
    },
    rect: {
      width: width,
      height: height,
      rx: 5,
      ry: 5,
      stroke: '#555',
      'magnet': true
    }
  }
});
```

And for the paper:

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
  el: $('#paper-basic'),
  width: 1250,
  height: 1000,
  model: graph,
  gridSize: 1,
  validateConnection: function(cellViewS, magnetS, cellViewT, magnetT, end, linkView) {
    // Prevent linking from output ports to input ports within one element.
    if (cellViewS === cellViewT) return false;
    // Prevent linking to input ports.
    return magnetT;
  },
  markAvailable: true
});
```

How can I require every link to have a source and a target? Maybe by extending `validateConnection`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is still relevant, there is now a option called `linkPinning` on `Paper` element:

http://jointjs.com/api#dia.Paper.prototype.options

> linkPinning - when set to true (the default), links can be pinned to
>   the paper meaning a source or target of a link can be a point. If you
>   do not want to let the user to drag a link and drop it somewhere in a
>   blank paper area, set this to false. The effect is that the link will
>   be returned to its original position whenever the user drops it
>   somewhere in a blank paper area.

Comment: link pinning did not work for me when using ports. when dragging a new link from a port to a blank area the link does not move or disappear. moving from a blank area to a blank area also did not revert the links position.

Answer (score 3):

slightly different/shorter answer combining @Anora s and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jointjs/vwGWDFWVDJI

```
paper.on('cell:pointerup', function (cellView, evt) {
    var elem = cellView.model
    var source = elem.get('source')
    var target = elem.get('target')
    if (elem instanceof joint.dia.Link && (!source.id || !target.id)) {
        elem.remove()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Validate Connection will only help with validating magnets, it doesn't get called when the end of the link is in random space on the paper.  You can remove incomplete links with the following:

```
// keep links from being incomplete
function isLinkInvalid(link){
    return (!link.prop('source/id') || !link.prop('target/id'));
}

paper.on('cell:pointerup', function(cellView) {
    if (! (cellView.model instanceof joint.dia.Link) ) return; // if it's not a link, don't worry about it
    // otherwise, add an event listener to it.  
    cellView.model.on('batch:stop', function(){
        var links = graph.getLinks();
        links.forEach(function(link){
            if(isLinkInvalid(link)){
                link.remove();
        }});
    });
});
```

It adds a eventListener to the link.  It's important to do it on `'cell:pointerup'` because a `'batch:stop'` is called when the link is created. If the link doesn't have a target id, then it isn't connected to a port.

Comment: how/where should I add this?

Comment: You should add this to the javascript after your paper/graph initialization.

Comment: I got it working by removing the line `cellView.model.on('batch:stop', function(){` .